# Oracle Listagg Sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

```
SELECT e.pem_id          AS id,
     e.pem_subject     AS subject,
     e.pem_content     AS content,
     e.pem_sent_date   AS sentdate,
     e.pem_ref_id      AS referenceid,
     e.pem_from_usr_id AS userid,
     NULL              AS misc,
     (listagg(str.str_us_id, ', ') within GROUP(ORDER BY '') AS attachedusers FROM
      proj_email_usrs eu LEFT OUTER JOIN st_register str ON
      eu.pmu_str_id = str.str_id WHERE eu.pmu_pem_id = '26' GROUP BY '')
FROM   proj_email e
WHERE  e.pem_prj_id = '33'
AND    e.pmu_pem_id = '26'
AND    e.pem_status = 'S';
```

It is throwing error as

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: I assume the back ticks are not really in your query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you want a query like this:

```
SELECT E.PEM_ID as Id, E.PEM_SUBJECT as Subject, E.PEM_CONTENT as Content,
       E.PEM_SENT_DATE as SentDate, E.PEM_REF_ID as ReferenceId,   
       E.PEM_FROM_USR_ID as UserId, NULL as Misc,
       (SELECT LISTAGG(STR.STR_US_ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STR.STR_US_ID)
        FROM PROJ_EMAIL_USRS EU LEFT OUTER JOIN
             ST_REGISTER STR
             ON EU.PMU_STR_ID = STR.STR_ID
        WHERE EU.PMU_PEM_ID = E.PMU_PEM_ID  -- Correlation clause
       ) as AttachedUsers
FROM PROJ_EMAIL E 
WHERE E.PEM_PRJ_ID = 33 AND E.PMU_PEM_ID = 26 AND E.PEM_STATUS = 'S' ;
```

Comments:

- Added the `SELECT` before `LISTAGG()`.  Needed for a subquery.
- Remove `GROUP BY`.  Not needed, because you want the subquery to always return one row.
- Removed single quotes from constants that are probably numbers.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- Added a correlation clause to the subquery.
- Moved the name of the column outside the subquery, so it is named in the result.
- Added an `ORDER BY` column for `WITHIN GROUP`.  Not necessary, but reasonable to keep the ids in order.

Comment: You made my day :) Thanks... works fine...  You have explained the reasons it's Commendable.

Comment: i'm getting this error for some lines using the LISTAGG on a LEFT JOIN clausule, but works after i swap to a subquery in this format. I really dont undertand why the error using the select in a LEFT JOIN appears just for some itens...

Comment: @AndreyHartung . . . If you have a question, ask a new *question*.